# Как сделать push/pull к закрытому репозиторию через логин и пароль?

Tags: git

С закрытыми репозиториями обычно работаю через ssh ключ.
Возникла необходимость работать через логин и пароль, и не понимаю как это сделать, если репозиторйи уже добавлен как `origin` и нужно только запушить через логин и пароль.

Comment: обновить адрес иди добавить новый remote пробовали?